# What is 'the morbid association between the cannibal and the nutcracker'?

Tags: anthony-marra, constellation-vital-phen

In Anthony Marra's "A Constellation of Vital Phenomena", Sonja remembers visiting an anatomy and pathology museum in London. There she stumbles upon an exhibit of a skull of a cannibal. The placard says:

> There are no characteristics to distinguish the cranium of a cannibal from that of an ordinary man

The next line says:

> The morbid association between the cannibal and the nutcracker ...

I am not sure I understood what association Sonja (or, rather, the author) had in mind. Is it simply due to the fact that Sonja bought the nutcracker the same day she visited the museum? I guess there is greater significance attached to it, something I failed to notice.

Comment: I do not know the text so can't give an actual answer, but I would presume the association here is one of cracking skulls like nut shells to eat what's inside.

Comment: Good point. I think I tried to look for a deeper meaning, but I guess the charm of this book comes from believable characters, who (just like people in the real world) on and off let their mind wonder about and derive quaint conclusions and associations. Or in the said case - morbid.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea that the "morbid association between the cannibal and the nutcracker" is "simply due to the fact that Sonja bought the nutcracker the same day she visited the museum" seems correct to me. Sonja remembers the nutcracker when she is searching for a sketch portrait of her missing sister Natasha:

> While searching, her mind flashed to the day she had purchased the Buckingham Palace Guard nutcracker. True to form it had endured flights across Europe, every bump of the Samsonite, and even the shame of Alu's name, without once breaking composure.
>
> She had found the nutcracker in a convenience store sticky with the residue of spilled soda, where stopped for cough drops before attending a lecture. It was four weeks to Christmas. The first war wouldn't officially begin for twelve more days. She had bought it without once thinking of Natasha, on a whim, because Buckingham Palace was what foreigners thought of when they thought of London and she, Sonja with a j, was nothing if not foreign.

Presumably the nutcracker is one like this:

[image: Nutcracker in the shape of the Royal Guard]

Having bought it, Sonja attends the lecture at the Royal College of Surgeons, then wanders through the museum there and sees the exhibited skull. Subconsciously, she might have made the association that Matt Thrower makes in his comment to your question: "cracking skulls like nut shells to eat what's inside". However, the text does not give any indication of this. The only connection the text itself makes is the one you note, that Sonja got the nutcracker on the same day that she saw the cannibal skull.

Sonja later gives the nutcracker to Natasha as a gift from her time in London. Natasha in turn gives it to Havaa, a young girl with whose family she has spent a couple of days while fleeing the war. Natasha subsequently disappears, and Havaa coincidentally ends up in Sonja's care. Sonja does not know what has happened to Natasha, nor does she know that Havaa has the nutcracker. But knowing that Havaa's family has sheltered many refugees in the past, Sonja asks whether Natasha ever stayed there. However, the name Natasha is too common for Havaa to be able to identify any one person. So Sonja looks for the sketch of Natasha, and while looking for it, remembers the nutcracker and its morbid association with the cannibal.

The nutcracker seems to acquire meaning by virtue of being associative. Sonja buys the nutcracker for its association with Buckingham Palace, one of the things foreigners associate with London. She gives it to Natasha as a souvenir of her time there, when the sisters were apart. Natasha parts with it because when she leaves Chechnya, she is also severing ties with Sonja. For no particular reason, the nutcracker comes to Sonja's mind when she is looking for a sketch of Natasha to show Havaa. And finally, when Sonja sees the nutcracker among Havaa's belongings, she tries to get details about Natasha's journey from Havaa, but all Havaa can say is that Natasha went away just as she came; she does not know any more. Sonja feels guilty about not having been able to save Natasha, but she does save Havaa, who grows up to get a PhD and become a scientist.

So the nutcracker has morbid associations as well as loving or hopeful ones, all the while being just a random object. It was purchased purely on a whim; it ends up with Havaa by chance; and it's coincidence that Havaa ends up in Sonja's care at the hospital where the latter is a doctor. In this way it's meaningful structurally and thematically, balancing cruelty, hope, and random chance in pretty much that same way that Marra's novel as a whole does.